# Uber api authorization with oAuth and intent handling

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, webview, uber-api

Uber provides an authorization url to get the user token. I am loading this url into a webview.

[image: Screenshot of the loaded url]

I handle the url in a webview client like this

```
 @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                Log.d("url=", "url = " + url);

                return true;
            }
```

Is there any way i can force a facebook login to go through the facebook app instead of the webview? (if it is installed)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Facebook login must go through the WebView.